# errer in code loading in perl

Tags: perl, progress-bar

What is the problem I do not want to Please Wait be repeated

```html
#!/usr/bin/perl
Win32::Console;
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(| / - \ );

my $i = 0;
my $v = "Please Wait";
print $chars[$i];

while (1) {
  sleep 1;
  print "$v\b", $chars[++$i % @chars];
}
```

What is the problem I do not want to Please Wait be repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `print "Please wait"` inside the while loop, so it will keep printing. Also use `\b` after the `$chars` print and not after `Please wait`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::Console;
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(| / - \ | / - \\);

my $i = 0;
my $v = "Please Wait";
print $v;
while (1) {
    sleep 1;
    print $chars[++$i % @chars],"\b";
}
```

Another option if you are planning on using a spinner is that you can get rid of `sleep 1;` ad replace it with select `undef, undef, undef, miliseconds`. If used like below the spinner will be nice and quick.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::Console;
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(| / - \ | / - \\);

my $i = 0;
my $v = "Please Wait ";
print $v;
while (1) {
    select undef, undef, undef, 0.05;
    print $chars[++$i % @chars],"\b";
}
```

EDIT, as per your comment to request using dots instead.
if you want to run `Please wait...` then get rid of the `\b`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::Console;
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(.);

my $i = 0;
my $v = "Please Wait";
print $v;
while (1) {
    sleep 1;
    print $chars[++$i % @chars];
}
```

Lastly, this is not a good method at all, but for a wait which resembles pretty much what you mentioned in the comment this will also work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$|++;
my @chars = qw( . | | | . .);
print "Please Wait ";
my $i = 0;
while (1) {
    select undef, undef, undef, .15;
    printf $chars[++$i % @chars];
    select undef, undef, undef, .15;
    printf $chars[++$i % @chars];
    select undef, undef, undef, .15;
    printf $chars[++$i % @chars];
    printf "\b\b\b";
}
```

It looks pretty neat when running though :)

Comment: Please, can you replace the | / - \ to  . . . .

Comment: That is exactly what this is doing. Copy the exact code and run it, you will see. The `,"\b"` at the very end will remove the previous character and replace with the new character each time the loop runs.

Comment: Please, can you replace the | / - \ to . . . .

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Do you want to start with `-` ?

Comment: I made a small edit. Please copy exact code and test.

Comment: yeah bro its word thnx but i ask if u can replace  | / - \  to .... par exmpl  #!/usr/bin/perl
use Win32::Console;
use strict;
use warnings;
$|++; # turn off output buffering;

my @chars = qw(. . . .);

my $i = 0;
my $v = "Please Wait";
print $v;
while (1) {
    sleep 1;
    print $chars[++$i % @chars],"\b";
}

Comment: ok, so now the question changed? Edited, see second piece of code. Please check and mark answer as correct if it works

Comment: Please Wait................ iwont only Please Wait.  /  Please Wait.. / Please Wait...

Comment: Sigh. then put the \b back.. See third piece of code.

Comment: I am not sure what you want now. this is getting unclear. You ask in the question that you need to not have Please wait repeated, then I answer, then you say you want to replace it with dots, then I do it, then you want only three dots? Can you edit your question and ask EXACTLY what you want?

Comment: That is not what your original question states. Please edit the question with EXACTLY what you need, or it will be flagged. The question was that you wanted to not repeat "Please wait". Nothing with dots.

Comment: The same idea two points and come back from the first https://jco.com.mt/Images/upload_in_progress.gif

Comment: Edit your question please and add what you want. Not comments.

Comment: see edits. Last one has similar timer like your gif file and second one is a faster spinner.